# ipython: "%history -g" prints huge amounts of base64 lines

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

After playing with images and plots for a while in `ipython notebook`, I have noticed that `%history -g` prints out huge number of output lines, mostly what seems to be base64.

The file `history.sqlite` has size of 1,2 MB

What is being logged in `history.sqlite` ?

history is supposed to log commands that I typed. All in all, I have not typed more than 1000 lines. What is the base64 stuff doing there. Please don' t tell me it is logging the images/pictures/plots that I generate. This would be insane.

Comment: It should never log images, only text output, and even that is only stored if you enable output logging in config. By default, only the input is logged. Could you have pasted in some base64 data at some point? You can examine the database using [SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: @Thomas K - I am not aware that I have pasted any base64 text as input. Looking with `SQLite browser` at the history file does not reveal much. It just shows individual sessions, their duration and number of commands stored. But it does not show the actual commands.

Comment: @Thomas K - looking at the output of `%history -g`, I see the base64 code starts with the following line:     `"  frames[28] = \"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAdQAAAC0CAYAAAAtpN2CAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlz\\\n",`

Comment: I guess you did at some point run code with a big block of base64 encoded data in. If it's long enough ago, you can run `ipython history trim` to trim the database to the last 1000 entries. Or you can edit it out with SQLite browser (you need to change to the history table - you were looking at the sessions table).

Comment: @Thomas K - what do you mean "I did run code with a big block of base64 encoded data" ? I did not enter any base64 data into the input cell. You mean the base64 was the output of my commands ? BTW, what is the parameter which disables output logging ?

Comment: Unless you have enabled output logging (which is disabled by default - the config option is `c.HistoryManager.db_log_output`), the only way it could get into your database is if you code containing that in some way.

Comment: @Thomas K - I am absolutely sure I have not typed this code into my input cell. And I have not changed `c.HistoryManager.db_log_output` either - it is set to default.

Comment: You needn't necessarily have typed it - you may have run a notebook, possibly even using runipy, that already contained it. Look at your history database, and you should be able to see what you were doing at the time.